# Resize div on screen resize

Tags: jquery, html

I want to refresh my div when a user resizes the screen of the browser so:

```
window.onresize = function(){ // Refresh div named: .divRefresh }
```

I don't have a clue how to do this.
Can somebody help me?

Comment: Do you mean to refresh as in pull data from an ajax call or to resize and redraw?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery `resize` function and `css` function. Where `divRefresh` is the class of your div.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $('.divRefresh').css('width', '500px'); //Write the size what you want.
});
```

If want the name, then you can use `$('div[name=divRefresh])`

Comment: No look, i use a slider called: Super simple Slider. And when a user resizes the screen, the slider adds a padding to the div ... and when you resize a small screen to a big screen the padding is HUGE, like 500px... So i want to reload the slider on resize.

Comment: but you did not mentioned that. 1: you can change the padding of your slider with the same function: `.css('padding', '10px');` or any value. 2. If it's not possible, then tell us, what plugin you use. 3. If it's not a plugin, then show us your code.